# Shiv'a v’Arbaim u’Shelosh Me’os Mi Yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows three hundred forty seven?

### שבעה וארבעים ושלוש מאות - מי יודע?‏

The traditional Passover song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea) implies a possible presupposition that there is a Jewish significance to be found for each [natural number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number). Accordingly, there is an [ongoing series](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) on Mi Yodeya that is attempting to unearth significant Judaism facts about each number, in sequence.

What significant Judaism facts are there about the number 347? The more significant within Judaism and the more intrinsically dependent on the value 347, the stronger the answer. Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

No lazy Gematria please. But given that we’ve already had questions on 666 and 366, counting doesn’t seem to be this series’ strong suit anyway.

Comment: It’s been a while since the last one in order so I thought I’d go ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

347 are the days where it is permitted to own Chametz in Israel (including partial days). (In a kesidran non-leap year.)

Answer (score 2):

347 are the days in a year in which a Bechor is permitted to eat, assuming he doesn't make a siyum.

Comment: In what kind of year?

Answer (score 1):

As per the calculations cited [here](http://cheshbon.weeklyshtikle.com/2009/10/how-many-in.html), there are 347 requests in Ya’aleh v’Yavo:

Most of them are in the first half, where we have eight verbs (יעלה...ויזכר) times six objects (זכרונינו...וזכרון כל עמך בית ישראל) times seven adjectives (לפליטה...ולשלום), yielding 336 requests (6x7x8).

In the second half, the list is more straightforward:

1. זכרינו בו לטובה
2. ופקדינו בו לברכה
3. והושעינו בו לחיים

The next clause, ובדבר ישועה ורחמים, gives two objects for the following four verbs:

1. חוס
2. וחננו
3. ורחם עלינו
4. והושיענו

Yielding 3+8 in the second half, plus the 336 from the first half, totals 347 requests.

Comment: What's with the -1?